# Efficient way to find duplicate/new in mongo db where there are many queried string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have about 1.5 million of existing user data in mongodb. I have to make a feature which will enable bulk importing user. Now I need to check whether this bulk imported user data namely emails are already present or not. If some of them are present and some of them are not, I'd like to know which are present and which are not.

For example say I have existing user emails `[ A, B, C, D, E, F ]` and the imported users have emails `[ C, D, X, Y, Z ]`. I'd like to know C, D can't be imported as these exist in the db, whereas X, Y, Z can be imported.

Currently I can query for each imported email in the db to check whether this particular email exists or not, but I fear the imported data can be large and this method will not be very efficient.

Is there any way to optimise ?

Answer (score 1):

one way would be to first put a unique index on the email field of the collection. then insert records in a try/catch block. whatever email/record that exists will throw an exception where you catch and do whatever you want with the failed entries.

alternatively, you could process two-three hundred import records at a time and issue the following command to see which emails already exists and shouldn't be imported.

```
db.collection.find(
    {
        email:
            { $in: ["C", "D", "X", "Y", "Z"] }
    }
)
```

then use a [bulkwrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/index.html) command to insert the records which are allowed to be inserted.